# Hosting Multiple TCP WCF service Endpoints on single Port

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding

I am hosting 3 WCF services inside windows services.Each WCF service contains Multiple endpoints. Right now, i am host all my endpoints thru TCP binding on different ports.
Is there any way to host all these end points from different wcf services on same port?

Answer (score 3):

Sure is! You can use the Net.TCP Port Sharing service.

[Net.TCP Port Sharing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734772.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: Thanks John. I will explore more on this and do some sample apps.

Comment: Hi John I set                                         <netTcpBinding>
       <binding name="potbinding" portSharingEnabled="True"/>       </netTcpBinding> in my config file.But i am end up below exception. Any help?System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: There is already a listener on IP endpoint 0.0.0.0:2324.  Make sure that you are not trying to use this endpoint multiple times in your application and that there are no other applications listening on this endpoint. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network ) is  permitted

Comment: @Vamsi: Hi. The port sharing service uses port 808 by default. Remove all the port numbers from your net.tcp urls, and they should default to 808.

Comment: @Thanks John. No luck i am still ending up w/ same issue.Here is my baseAddress of my 2 services   
         </netTcpBinding>                     <baseAddresses><add baseAddress="net.tcp://12.230.55.192/StudentService"/></baseAddresses>2)<baseAddresses><add baseAddress="net.tcp://12.230.55.192/PatentService"/>
</baseAddresses>. I also started Net Port sharing service. I really appreciate your help.Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

I just looked into that, out of curiosity. The behavior I discovered seems so strange that I almost don't want to put it here. But it worked in my case, so maybe it's doing the same for you:

I am getting the *AddressAlreadyInUseException* when I'm trying to host 2 services (i.e., 2 separate ServiceHost instances) on the same net.tcp port with `portSharingEnabled="True"` set on the netTcpBinding for both. That happens with or without the Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service running. The exception is thrown even if I only start one of the services (and I verified via `netstat` that there was no other listener on that same port on the machine, plus, I ran the app with elevated privileges).

Now, the funny thing is, the *AddressAlreadyInUseException* is not thrown when I set PortSharingEnabled = False, and yet both services are fully working!! Once again, with or without the Port Sharing Service running. I could even successfully connect to those services from a different machine.

An important note to make, however, is that the above only applies if the services are hosted within the SAME PROCESS! It does blow up if I try to start another instance of the app that's listening on the same port, but a different base address. But I'm assuming you're hosting those 3 WCF services inside the same Windows Service?

So, even though it doesn't seem right, my answer would be to **disable** `PortSharingEnabled` and see if it works with different BaseAddresses on the same port (provided they're all inside the same process).

Comment: Where you hosting these Services ? In side Windows Service or Windows Console or using "client:"WcfTestClient.exe". I tried testing the same on "client:"WcfTestClient.exe" but failed.

Comment: I'm hosting them in a Console app, so that's comparable to a Windows Service since you're instantiating the ServiceHost explicitly.

Comment: @Vamsi and @ServiceGuy: Is metadata exchange enabled on these endpoints? If so, try disabling it. @ServiceGuy, enabling port sharing on the MEX endpoint may make it behave as expected.

Comment: @JohnC: Removed the MEX endpoints, and also the MetadataBehavior, and it's still working fine *without* `PortSharingEnabled`. Or is that not what you were after?

Comment: Yes, yes. I believe this post from Nicholas Allen's blog explains the unexpected behavior: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2006/08/23/713297.aspx.

Comment: you wouldn't believe how long i've been messing around till i read this post. this should have been in the docs exactly like you explain it here.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you not only have to enable port sharing on the configuration (or via code), you also have to manually start the Windows Port Sharing service.

That's the reason why I (having similar problem) didn't want to use port sharing, to make it easier for deployment rather than having to mess with other things the user may or may not know.