# how do I run multiple WCF services on one port?

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hosting Multiple TCP WCF service Endpoints on single Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889596/hosting-multiple-tcp-wcf-service-endpoints-on-single-port)

I have 4 services running from one WCF service application, and it all works great if use 4 separate ports and is running on my local machine, hosted in a console app.  That's fine for development, but now I want to move it to a Server 2008 machine on the intranet, and the IT boys aren't real happy about opening up a slew of ports on that machine.

I know I can run multiple services on the same port, but I can't seem to find anything telling me how to do so.  Mostly, the first service starts up and then the second one fails to start.

Can anybody point me to a blog or article that explains how to do this?

I also need to figure out how to host the services in WAS, but that may be a separate issue.  I am using TCP protocol, if that makes any difference...

Thx, Dave

Comment: You are correct, it is a duplicate.  My search terms somehow did not find that one yesterday, I apologize...

Answer (score 8):

This looks like it could do the trick for you.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dkaufman/archive/2008/06/13/hosting-multiple-service-implementation-on-the-same-port-with-wcf.aspx

Which suggests that you need to set up the service behavior and endpoint correctly:

```
// Add behavior for Services - enable WSDL access
ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceABehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
serviceABehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
serviceABehavior.HttpGetUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/ServiceA");
serviceAHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceABehavior);

ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceBBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
serviceBBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
serviceBBehavior.HttpGetUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/ServiceB");
serviceBHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceBBehavior);

// Create basicHttpBinding endpoint at http://localhost:8080/ServiceA/  
serviceAHost.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceAContractType, new BasicHttpBinding(), 
"http://localhost:8080/ServiceA");
// Create basicHttpBinding endpoint at http://localhost:8080/ServiceB/  
serviceBHost.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceBContractType, new BasicHttpBinding(), 
"http://localhost:8080/ServiceB");
```

---

Or Net.TCP port sharing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734772.aspx

> The HTTP.SYS model in which traffic for many different HTTP applications is multiplexed onto a single TCP port has become standard on the Windows platform. This provides a common point of control for firewall administrators while allowing application developers to minimize the deployment cost of building new applications that can make use of the network.

Comment: I found the referenced blog post earlier yesterday, but was hoping for a more elegant solution.  The writer admits in his post it is not the ideal solution, as it uses hard-coded URIs instead of using the config file, among other things.  The port sharing approach seems like it could be a better solution...

Comment: First link is broken.